What is the unsignifiability paradox?
Okay, so I was reading about Bhratri’s perspectivism on the Wikipedia page for Liar Paradox :
“ The Indian grammarian-philosopher Bhartrhari (late fifth century AD) dealt with paradoxes such as the liar in a section of one of the chapters of his magnum opus the Vākyapadīya.[citation needed] Bhartrhari's solution fits into his general approach to language, thought and reality, which has been characterized by some as "relativistic", "non-committal" or "perspectivistic".[17] With regard to the liar paradox (sarvam mithyā bravīmi "everything I am saying is false") Bhartrhari identifies a hidden parameter that can change unproblematic situations in daily communication into a stubborn paradox. Bhartrhari's solution can be understood in terms of the solution proposed in 1992 by Julian Roberts: "Paradoxes consume themselves. But we can keep apart the warring sides of the contradiction by the simple expedient of temporal contextualisation: what is 'true' with respect to one point in time need not be so in another ... The overall force of the 'Austinian' argument is not merely that 'things change', but that rationality is essentially temporal in that we need time in order to reconcile and manage what would otherwise be mutually destructive states."[18] According to Robert's suggestion, it is the factor "time" which allows us to reconcile the separated "parts of the world" that play a crucial role in the solution of Barwise and Etchemendy.[16]: 188  The capacity of time to prevent a direct confrontation of the two "parts of the world" is here external to the "liar". In the light of Bhartrhari's analysis, however, the extension in time that separates two perspectives on the world or two "parts of the world" – the part before and the part after the function accomplishes its task – is inherent in any "function": also the function to signify which underlies each statement, including the "liar".[5][clarification needed] The unsolvable paradox – a situation in which we have either contradiction (virodha) or infinite regress (anavasthā) – arises, in case of the liar and other paradoxes such as the unsignifiability paradox (Bhartrhari's paradox), when abstraction is made from this function (vyāpāra) and its extension in time, by accepting a simultaneous, opposite function (apara vyāpāra) undoing the previous one.”
And like I can hardly find any information about the unsignifiability paradox. If I am not mistaken, Bhratri’s paradox is that if you consider something to be unsignifiable or unnameable, it becomes signifiable or nameable because you are talking about it. So as such pretty much everything is signifiable or nameable except for maybe things that humans can’t even think of.
But what is signifiable mean and nameable mean? Are they synonyms? And how is it related to Liar’s Paradox or Bhratri’s perpsectivism?

"The Tao that can be named is not the eternal Tao. The Name that can be spoken is not the eternal name." Th paradox can be easily googled as "Bhartrhari's paradox", see e.g. Herzbergers. It has the same self-defeating flavor as the Liar, the stronger the arguments for unnameable things, "the more firmly they undercut their own conclusions; for they naturally tend to involve repeated reference to the very things whose unnameability they undertake to establish." Even closer to it is the Berry paradox.
